# Can't load my template file

Tags: 7, theming

My `human.tpl.php` file is located in `/tpl` folder. Im trying to use `hook_theme` from the module:

```
    function human_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
        $item['human'] = array(
            'template' => 'human',
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'human').'/tpl',
            'type' => 'theme',
            'variables' => array(),
        ),
    );
    return $item;
}
```

Why is this not working? I have some basic html code in my template file for testing purposes so it should show me something, but I get nothing back. If more information is needed, please let me know and I will add. Full code of a `.module` file can be found [here.](http://paste.ofcode.org/SphGJpuuCd6SAMhg6FBcKu)

Comment: remove `type`, its automatically derived from module/theme. Also you've not implemented `template_preprocess_human()` function which will define value of all your template file variables. Defining preprocess function might help.

Answer (score 1):

You have two returns (the second will never be hit). You have declared your array twice. It should be this:

```
function human_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'human' => array(
      'template' => 'human',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'human').'/tpl',
      'type' => 'theme',
      'variables' => array(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't show any of my template code which is just a simple `div` with "test" string

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Answer (score 0):

In order for Drupal to find these new template files specified in hook_theme() you have to also clear the theme cache.

Also look into theme debugging for Drupal which will show you theme suggestions that show which template files are being used to generate sections of a page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers, I used all of your suggestions, but the problem was with `_page()` function. After going through multiple examples I realized that I have to return `$render_array`, so now my `human_page` function looks like this:

```
function human_page(){
    //LOAD CUSTOM CONTENT TYPE FROM DB
    $result = entity_load('node', false, array('type' => 'human'));

    $render_array = array(
        '#theme' => 'human',
        '#items' => $result,
        '#title' =>t('ARGUMENT'),
    );
    return $render_array;
}
```

Lesson learned: Don't return simple variables in a page function because it will not work :)

Comment: Why wouldn't node be a variable passed in? You also are not passing a variables array to your function.